# Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, join, random, derived

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `snap`.`ID`, `user`.`username`, `vote`.`type` 
FROM (`snap`) JOIN `user` as u ON `u`.`ID` = `snap`.`user` 
LEFT JOIN (select * from vote where user = "18") as vote ON `snap`.`ID` = `vote`.`snap` 
JOIN (SELECT CEIL(MAX(ID)*RAND()) AS ID FROM snap)) AS x ON `snap`.`ID` => `x`.`ID` 
WHERE `snap`.`active` = 0 LIMIT 1
```

It worked just fine untill I added the last JOIN. Now i get the error: "Every derived table must have its own alias". I know it is because every table needs its on alias and I need to put "as S" or something somewhere, but I can't find out how to do that in this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have extra closing parenthesis after snap. It should be 1 instead of 2 closing parentheses.

```
SELECT `snap`.`ID`, `user`.`username`, `vote`.`type` 
FROM (`snap`) JOIN `user` as u ON `u`.`ID` = `snap`.`user` 
LEFT JOIN (select * from vote where user = "18") as vote ON `snap`.`ID` = `vote`.`snap` 
JOIN (SELECT CEIL(MAX(ID)*RAND()) AS ID FROM snap) AS x ON `snap`.`ID` = `x`.`ID` 
WHERE `snap`.`active` = 0 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: yeah I got it working. Really really thanks !! Btw, I also changed the => because that gave an other error.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is :

```
SELECT `snap`.`ID`, `user`.`username`, `vote`.`type`
FROM (`snap`) JOIN `user` as u ON `u`.`ID` = `snap`.`user`
LEFT JOIN (select * from vote where user = "18") as vote ON `snap`.`ID` = `vote`.`snap`
JOIN (SELECT CEIL(MAX(ID)*RAND()) AS ID FROM snap) AS x ON `snap`.`ID` = `x`.`ID`
WHERE `snap`.`active` = 0 LIMIT 1
```